# SQL Server query XML structure

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I had a xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfFMADevice>

   <DeviceID xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">72979</DeviceID>
    <CreationDate xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">2017-04-12T02:13:44.257</CreationDate>
    <Manufacturer xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">RICOH</Manufacturer>
    <Model xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">MP C2004</Model>
      <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
        <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
        <Name>PageCountTotal</Name>
        <Value>6193</Value>
      </FMAMeter>
      <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
        <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
        <Name>PageCountMono</Name>
        <Value>3159</Value>
      </FMAMeter>
      <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
        <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
        <Name>PageCountPrinter</Name>
        <Value>4919</Value>
      </FMAMeter>
</FMADevice>
</ArrayOfFMADevice>
```

I need record in this format :

```
DeviceID ||CreationDate || Manufacturer || Model ||  Date || PageCountTotal ||   PageCountMono ||  PageCountPrinter
```

can anyone guide ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What have **you tried** so far??

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

The XML is not well-formed. I had to fix it.

You didn't really share your desired output based on the actual XML. Please edit your original post and provide a real desired output.

In the meantime, please try the SQL below. It will give you a good head start.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfFMADevice>
    <FMADevice>
        <DeviceID xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">72979</DeviceID>
        <CreationDate xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">2017-04-12T02:13:44.257</CreationDate>
        <Manufacturer xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">RICOH</Manufacturer>
        <Model xmlns="http://www.fmaudit.com/">MP C2004</Model>
        <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
            <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
            <Name>PageCountTotal</Name>
            <Value>6193</Value>
        </FMAMeter>
        <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
            <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
            <Name>PageCountMono</Name>
            <Value>3159</Value>
        </FMAMeter>
        <FMAMeter Version="4.4.85.17052">
            <Date>2020-04-24T08:06:13.26</Date>
            <Name>PageCountPrinter</Name>
            <Value>4919</Value> 
        </FMAMeter>
    </FMADevice>
</ArrayOfFMADevice>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.fmaudit.com/' AS ns1)
SELECT header.c.value('(ns1:DeviceID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [DeviceID]
    , header.c.value('(ns1:CreationDate/text())[1]','DATETIME') AS [CreationDate]
    , header.c.value('(ns1:Manufacturer/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Manufacturer]
    , header.c.value('(ns1:Model/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Model]
    , body.c.value('(Date/text())[1]','DATETIME') AS [Date]
    , body.c.value('(Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Name]
    , body.c.value('(Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [Value]
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfFMADevice/FMADevice') AS header(c)
    CROSS APPLY header.c.nodes('FMAMeter') AS body(c);
```

> Output

```
+----------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+------------------+-------+
| DeviceID |      CreationDate       | Manufacturer |  Model   |          Date           |       Name       | Value |
+----------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+------------------+-------+
|    72979 | 2017-04-12 02:13:44.257 | RICOH        | MP C2004 | 2020-04-24 08:06:13.260 | PageCountTotal   |  6193 |
|    72979 | 2017-04-12 02:13:44.257 | RICOH        | MP C2004 | 2020-04-24 08:06:13.260 | PageCountMono    |  3159 |
|    72979 | 2017-04-12 02:13:44.257 | RICOH        | MP C2004 | 2020-04-24 08:06:13.260 | PageCountPrinter |  4919 |
+----------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+------------------+-------+
```